# css align footer bottom without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position, show

I have a website made of "pages" (100% height on visible area). Please look at the following css:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body{
height:100%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.page{
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 700px;
min-width: 1024px;
}

.content {
margin: 0 auto; 
text-align: center; 
height: 100%;
min-height: 800px;
min-width: 1024px;
}

.footer {
width: 100%;
min-height: 200px;
background-color:red;
}

 .hidden{
width: 100%;
height: 500px;
background-color:blue;
   }

.image {
display:block;
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

And this is the code:

```
  <div class="page">
     <div class="content">

        <img class="image" src="img/image.png1"> 
        <img class="image" src="img/image.png2"> 
        <img class="image" src="img/image.png3">   

        <div class="hidden" style="visibility:hidden">
        </div>

     </div>

     <div class="footer">
     </div>

  </div>
```

I need:
1) the footer to be aligned bottom when the page loads
2) after some seconds, with javascript I show the hidden div, and the footer must slide down.

I can't obtain these two things at the same time, because I can obtain 1) with

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but in this way when I show the hidden div it overlaps the footer.
Otherwise if I remove this last code, when the hidden div appears the footer slides down correctly, but when I load the page the footer is not at the bottom.
Does someone have any advice?

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: Just remove the footer style at the same moment you make the div visible.

Comment: Is this eligible for upvote?

Comment: I think there are many solution for this but I can't really picture this issue without seeing a proper http://jsfiddle.net to see what kind of interaction is ideal for this

Comment: Ok I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4DhL/4/

Comment: Fiddle updated to better understand: http://jsfiddle.net/t4DhL/5

Comment: @Turnip He is required to post a complete example of his code here, **not** a jsfiddle which will get this question closed. [mcve]

Comment: @Rob this question is 3.5 years old.

Comment: Yes. I saw that afterwards but it needs to have the point made for anyone thinking using jsfiddle is OK for posting code by itself so I'm leaving it here.

Answer (score 1):

How about;

```
position: relative;
bottom: -100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is the following code:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color:red;
    margin-top: 100vp;
}
```

The thing is that the footer is not seen until the user scrolls, you could 
give it a less than a 100vp margin-top but it depends on the footer height which can change.

**NOTE:** vp means viewport height

Answer (score -1):

You should try with this code:

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This is the absolute perfect answer in any other case, but i came here to exactly not get this standard answer (as said in the title: no position:absolute)